# form_for using polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, form-for, nested-form-for

I have a user model which can have many transactions. A transaction can be either of type1, type2 or type3, with each type having different set of attributes. For ex: type1 contain attributes a, b, and c; while type2 contains attributes a, c, d and e. User, Transaction and Type model are as defined below:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :transactionable, polymorphic: true
end

class Type1 < AR::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable
end

class Type2 < AR::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable
end

class Type3 < AR::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable
end
```

Now, in generating html form, I have

```
/app/views/user/new.html.erb

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ***
<% end %>

/app/views/user/show.html.erb

<%= form_for ... do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field: a %>
  <%= f.text_field: b %>
  <%= f.text_field: c %>
<% end %>
```

In the later form_for helper, I want to collect user input data for attributes of type1 model. Can anyone help with what should go in ... in the later form_for helper? I tried @user.transactions.build_type1, but it is showing error. Any idea what could have gone wrong?